# Lightspeed and Mass=Gravity

Tags: gravity, mass, speed-of-light

As an object approaches the speed of light, its observed mass becomes infinitely large -- Does the Gravity of the object show a corresponding increase and become infinitely large?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a mass moves close to the speed of light, does it turn into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/)

Comment: Related: [Does a high-speed particle weigh more?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693723/)

Comment: You are currently moving arbitrarily close to the speed of light in an appropriately chosen frame.  Do you notice other objects trying hard to cling to you?

Comment: Yes, but it is not simply a scalar multiplication with the gammafactor but vector dependend, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/718466/24093